# greedy block ()* contains wildcard

Tags: regex, antlr, grammar, greedy, antlr4

I am building a grammar in `ANTLR4`, and I am getting this warning

`TL4.g4:224:12: greedy block ()* contains wildcard; the non-greedy syntax ()*? may be preferred`

Here is the line of code it is referring to

```
block
    : ( statement | functionDecl )* (Return expression ';')?
    ;
```

What does the warning mean, How can I correct it ?

Comment: it's an old question, but still, I would like to share the ANTLR documentation, which provides further clarification on the topic:
https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/wildcard.md

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The warning is telling you that the block `()*` is greedy, meaning that it will try to match maximum occurrences of `statement` or `functionDec1` which, depending on the situation, might not be what you expect.

Changing it to `()*?` makes it non-greedy, as suggested by the warning. This means it will match minimum occurrences of `statement` or `functionDec1`.

Expression examples with strings:

Samples:

```
foofoobar
foobarbar
foofoobarbarbar
```

Expression:

```
(foo|bar)*bar
```

Will give result:

```
foofoobar
foobarbar
foofoobarbarbar
```

Expression:

```
(foo|bar)*?bar
```

Will give result:

```
foofoobar
foobar
foofoobar
```

For the last one, the result will stop at the first `bar`

Comment: can you please add some examples

Comment: @mataug How about those string match examples?

Comment: I'm a little late to the party, but is there any way to suppress this warning? What if I want to capture all of the text between /* and */? Would it not be best  to take the greedy approach?

Comment: @JohnSmith Not that I'm aware of, and that'd be risky, unless you know there's exactly 1 of these `/* ... */` in the text, because if not, then you will get everything from the first `/*` to the last `*/` with no regards to whether there is another `*/` in the middle of those.

Comment: @Jerry, so that's what it's saying. Okay that makes a lot of sense! Thank you.